# How to autofit an item using setSpanSizeLookup?

Tags: android, tags, grid, gridlayoutmanager, staggered-gridview

I am trying to make this type of layout using `setSpanSizeLookup` by `GridLayoutManager`.

Does anyone know how to autofit an item by calculating width of the item and auto adjust like image?

If there is some another way then please suggest me.

Here is some code:

```
int maxWidth = 1040; // device width
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_favorite, null);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        int itemWidth = (int) (textView.getPaint().measureText(favoriteList.get(position).getName()));

        if ((maxWidth / 2) / 3 > itemWidth) {
            return 1;
        } else if ((maxWidth / 2) / 3 < itemWidth && maxWidth / 3 > itemWidth) { 
            return 2;
        } else if (maxWidth / 2 > itemWidth && maxWidth / 3 < itemWidth) {
            return 3;
        }
    }
});
```

[Please check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YYZD.png)

Comment: Check this [library](https://github.com/DavidPizarro/AutoLabelUI)

Comment: I want to show large amount of record so I prefer to use recyclerView, I have applied some library but they freez view and etc. I am near with above method but sometime calculation goes wrong. I think **setSpanSizeLookup** is proper way.. looking forward.. Thanks for suggest library @BurakCakir

Comment: If the view doesn't freeze in the method you are applying and only the problem is in the calculation, you can apply the above library's calculation to your own code.

Comment: now it is available.. may it will help us. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html

Answer (score 1):

We have the option of `FlexboxLayout` now.

For layout,

```
<com .google.android.flexbox.flexboxlayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     app:flexwrap="wrap">
```

We have also layout manager for dynamic handle by `recyclerView`

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager();
```

Enjoy..!!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17261781)

Comment: @Antti29 Thank you for guide me. everyone is new at some stage. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add flexbox dependency

> compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.1'

And set **FlexboxLayoutManager**

```
    FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
    layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
    layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```